# The distance between the centers of two circles K1 and K2 is 2cm. Determine the surface area of the figure that belongs to both circles.

Tags: geometry, circles

The distance between the centers of two circles K1 and K2 is 2cm. They intersect under a right angle, the radius of K1 is 1cm. Determine the surface area of the figure that belongs to both circles.

[[image: This is a little sketch.[1]]

So I drew it like this. It is obvious that the radius of K2 is then the square root of 3. I have no idea how to get the surface area of this weird shape. Any tips?

Comment: By "surface area", do you mean perimeter or area within the shape?

Comment: @BenedictRandallShaw area within the shape that is the union of both circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the area of a circular cap as shown below. Two such circular caps produce your 'weird shape'.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't look anything like the shape I am supposed to get?

Comment: If you draw a vertical line between the two points of intersection of your two circles, you will see that this divides your shape into two such caps...attached back-to-back

Comment: I did it! Thanks for the help!!!